Y.applyUpdate(doc, new Uint8Array(update)) is not updating the existing Ydoc consistently,
I am building a collaborative editor for my canvas editor, I am using Yjs for the collaborative editor. For every change one client is doing i am receiving that update at the backend and updating my yjs doc at the backend. I am using React and Nodejs along with sockets.
But one problem I am facing with this backend code (given), my backend Yjs doc is not updating and it's saving the older data to Redis. I am adding both backend and frontend code.

Canvas is JSON  objects of elements

Any help will be grateful.
Yjs version Node : yjs13.6.18
Yjs version React :  yjs :13.0.0-103
    // Frontend React Code
    const ymap = doc.getMap('json');
    ymap.set('data', designer.canvas);
    const update = Y.encodeStateAsUpdate(doc);
    if (socket) socket.emit('update', { update, id });
    // Backend Node code
    socket.on('update', async ({update, id}) => {
      doc.transact(() => {
      Y.applyUpdate(doc, new Uint8Array(update));
      });
      let updatedJson = ymap.get('data');
    }

I tried this Y.applyUpdate() & Y.diffUpdate() but some times my older data is not updating :
